# UpdatePanelAnimationExtender always firing

Tags: asp.net, ajax, updatepanelanimationexte

Is there any way to prevent an UpdatePanelAnimationExtender from executing when the associated updatepanel is not updating (i.e. is set to conditional updates)?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is a known "bug" in the control. As of this posting it still hasn't been fixed and there is no known workaround. So the answer is no you can't prevent it.